# How to convert Excel to Html using OpenXml

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openxml

Currently, I can convert Word to Html using OpenXml with ConvertToHtml method. But I can not apply this method for SpeardSheetDocument file (xlxs). So how can I similarly convert the excel file to Html via OpenXml. Or is there any other approach for my situation ? It would be better if I can convert powerpoint file (ppt) to Html too.

I know there is a library called Interop but if I use this I need to install microsoft office, but I dont want to install those softwares.

Thank all !

Comment: I don't know if there is a out-of-the-box solution to convert to html, but to read xlsx, [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) or [Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) are easier to use than OpenXml. You can then create a html yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and after research, I found some library can do the same thing, its name is ClosedXml.